# How to resolve a constructor console error in p5.js - data visual

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am basically trying to implement the bubble code (this code will just display the data from the csv file and display them in a bubble ellipse)  into a data visualization template and the bubble code should be in an external constructor (meaning it should be in another file with the constructor name). To give u a general idea, i'm making a few tabs and once a tab is clicked - its designated code(constructor) will run.
I created a tab named as 'Food Data in Bubbles' and when that tab is clicked, the constructor should be called.

I don't have any problem with calling the constructor. The thing im having an issue with is that when the constructor is called, it gives an console error as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC9Z2.png)

I want to know how i can resolve this Issue. Just for reference, I'll provide you with the files and code.

This is the index file that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="lib/p5.min.js"></script>
<!-- Main sketch file -->
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
<script src="bubble.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <ul id="visuals-menu"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the sketch file:

```
var dataTable;
var myScatter;
var data;
var bubbles = [];
var maxAmt;
var years = [];
var yearButtons = [];

function preload()
{
  dataTable = loadTable('data/tech-diversity/gender-2018.csv', 'header');
    data = loadTable("data/bubble/foodData.csv", "csv", "header");
}

function setup() {
  // Create a canvas to fill the content div from index.html.
  var c = createCanvas(1024, 576);
  c.parent('app');

  // Add the visualisation objects here.
  gallery.addVisual(new BubbleData());
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  if (gallery.selectedVisual != null) {
    gallery.selectedVisual.draw();
  }

  translate(width/2, height/2);
    for(var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++)
    {
        bubbles[i].update(bubbles);
        bubbles[i].draw();
    }
}
```

and this is the main Constructor file:

```
function BubbleData() {

    // Name for the visualisation to appear in the menu bar.
    this.name = 'Food Data in Bubbles';
  
    // Each visualisation must have a unique ID with no special
    // characters.
    this.id = 'bubble-data';
  
    // Property to represent whether data has been loaded.
    this.loaded = false;
  
  
    this.setup = function() {
        var rows = data.getRows();
        var numColumns = data.getColumnCount();
        
        for(var i = 5; i < numColumns; i++)
        {
            var y = data.columns[i];
            years.push(y);
            b = createButton(y,y);
            b.parent('years')
            b.mousePressed(function()
            {
               changeYear(this.elt.value);
            })
            yearButtons.push(b);
            
            
        }
        
        
        maxAmt = 0;
        
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            if(rows[i].get(0) != "")
            {
                var b = new Bubble(rows[i].get(0));
                
                for(var j = 5; j < numColumns; j++)
                {
                    if(rows[i].get(j) != "")
                    {
                        var n = rows[i].getNum(j);
                        if(n > maxAmt)
                        {
                            maxAmt = n; //keep a tally of the highest value
                        }
                        b.data.push(n);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         b.data.push(0);
                    }
                    
                }
                
                bubbles.push(b);
            }
            
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++)
        {
            bubbles[i].setData(0);
        }
    };
  
    function changeYear(year)
    {
        var y = years.indexOf(year);
        
        for(var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++)
        {
            bubbles[i].setData(y);
        }
    };
  
    // Create a new pie chart object.
    this.pie = new PieChart(width / 2, height / 2, width * 0.4);
  
    this.draw = function() {
        translate(width/2, height/2);
        for(var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++)
        {
            bubbles[i].update(bubbles);
            bubbles[i].draw();
        }
    };

    this.Bubble = function(_name)
    {
        this.size = 20;
        this.target_size = 20;
        this.pos = createVector(0,0);
        this.direction = createVector(0,0);
        this.name = _name;
        this.color = color(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255));
        this.data = [];
        
        this.draw = function()
        {
            push();
            textAlign(CENTER);
            noStroke();
            fill(this.color);
            ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size);
            fill(0);
            text(this.name,this.pos.x,this.pos.y);
            pop();
        };
        
        this.update = function(_bubbles)
        {
            this.direction.set(0,0);
            
            for(var i = 0; i < _bubbles.length; i++)
            {
                if(_bubbles[i].name != this.name)
                {
                    var v = p5.Vector.sub(this.pos,_bubbles[i].pos); 
                    var d = v.mag();

                    if(d < this.size/2 + _bubbles[i].size/2)
                    {
                        if(d > 0)
                        {
                            
                            this.direction.add(v)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.direction.add(p5.Vector.random2D());    
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            this.direction.normalize();
            this.direction.mult(2);
            this.pos.add(this.direction);
            
            if(this.size < this.target_size)
            {
                this.size += 1;
            }
            else if(this.size > this.target_size)
            {
                this.size -= 1;
            }
        
        };
        
        this.setData = function(i)
        {
            this.target_size = map(this.data[i], 0, maxAmt, 20, 250);
        };
        
        
    };
}
```

there is another file which is the helper function file through which I'm calling this function and other task but that's unnecessary here, the only problem here is with the constructor file

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).